# How to redistribute vc++ application from visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, side-by-side

I have developed a application in VC++ (Visual Studio 2008 version '9.0.30729.1SP').

When i just double click on exe file in another machine. it is giving me 'side by side' error.

I have checked that machine does not having anything inside 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC' folder. (but having framework 3.5 installed)

What i need to do?I am very new in VC++ applications.

Please can anyone explain  how can i merge everything into a setup from machine where i have compiled my application.

Even 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC' folder also.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to create a setup program. It will automatically install all necessary dependencies onto the user's machine, along with your application. You definitely don't want to try to find all of the libraries it depends on by manually scouring your drive. And static linking is generally not a preferred option, as it means your app won't automatically take advantage of updates made to the runtime DLLs.

Visual Studio even has out-of-the-box support for creating an installer for your application. To use it, select File -> New -> New Project. Then expand "Other Project Types" in the dialog, and expand "Setup and Deployment". Click on "Visual Studio Installer", and choose to create a new "Setup Project".

[image]

Or, if you'd rather not use Visual Studio, the free, full-featured [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is a fantastic alternative.

Comment: Thanks.Are it will also include 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC' folder?Will try.

Comment: @prashant: No, it won't include that entire folder. But you don't need the entire folder just to run the application. It *will* include the files that it needs.

Comment: one more thing when i try to run the exe on another machine which is having VS2008 installed then also i am getting error saying 'the application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect' any idea.

Comment: @prashant: Yup, they're there in VS 2008. At least in the Professional Edition. I've updated my screenshot to match that version (as I would have done in the first place, had I been paying more attention). Are you by chance using the *Express* edition? It might not come with support for creating a setup project. In that case, you either need to obtain a full version of VS, or look elsewhere for installer options. I recommended Inno Setup in my answer, it's one of my personal favorites.

Comment: Now I have created setup using VS2008.I am added merge modlude for Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm and all.But still unable to work on different machine. As you can see here my manifest file requires different versions of dll..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945312/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-the-application-is-incorrect. So i installed all versions Vcredist_x86.exe and it works....

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en) on the other machine. This will ensure that all the required CRT libraries are available. If your application needs any other DLLs,  they need to be in the same folder (or in the system path) as your application.

If you want to do it properly, I highly recommend [Cody's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936724/how-to-redistribute-vc-application-from-visual-studio-2008/5936794#5936794) answer. But if you want to quickly run an application which may or may not have external DLLs, then this method will work.

Comment: Yeah, installing the redistributable is still way better than trying to copy the files over manually, though. I've seen an unfortunately number of people asking questions here after trying to deploy applications compiled in Debug mode dependent upon debug versions of the CRT or MFC DLLs.

Comment: @Cody: Yeah, I don't think even redistributables can fix the whole "manifest hell" issue with VS. Have you ever encountered that with the setup file method?

Comment: No, an installer generally gets this type of thing right. At least, I haven't had a problem yet. But I also do a lot more static linking for C++ code than I might recommend to others. Typically, if I've chosen to use C++ rather than .NET, it's because I want the code to run with as few dependencies as absolutely possible.