# The application has failed to start because the application is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am getting this error while execution of my application.
I am using VS 2008 version '9.0.30729.1 SP' on Windows Server 2008.

[image]

Here is my manifest file description

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.30729.4148" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT" version="9.0.30729.1" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Can anybody explain why it requires both version of 'Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT' as you can see in manifest file. version '9.0.21022.8' and '9.0.30729.4148'.

I have seen in my folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\ Microsoft.VC90.CRT' the 'msvcm90.dll' version are '9.0.30729.1'

Are the error is because of this?

I have seen under system event showing 3 errors are as follows.

1. Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT could not be found and Last Error was The
   referenced assembly is not installed on your system.
2. Resolve Partial Assembly failed for Microsoft.VC90.CRT. Reference error message: The
   referenced assembly is not installed on your system.
3. Generate Activation Context failed for d:\Barriergates\Debug\Barriergates.exe.Manifest.
   Reference error message: The operation completed successfully.

Please help in these issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some special steps you must take to run your Debug EXE on a test machine.  See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).